# Low salary in Marie-Curie Fellowship

Tags: funding, marie-curie

I received Marie Curie global fellowship to go to US from Sweden. I think the salary I was told to have is too low. 3400 USD/month after tax (4657 USD/month before tax). Please let me know if you think it is too low and who can I try to contact to sort it out.

I will send 2 years in US and 1 year in Sweden, however, I was told to receive flat salary of around 4100EUR before tax and around 3000EUR after

Answer (score 5):

From the [Guide to Implementation](https://ec.europa.eu/research/mariecurieactions/document/your-msca-individual-fellowship-a-guide-to-implementation), if you moved to Sweden, your gross monthly salary (at minimum) should be composed of a living allowance of €4880 plus a mobility allowance of €600 multiplied by a country correction coefficient, which can be found [in this document, table 2](https://ec.europa.eu/research/participants/data/ref/h2020/wp/2018-2020/main/h2020-wp1820-msca_en.pdf) and which is 1.218 for Sweden. Thus, your gross monthly allowance calculated in this way would be €6674.

In this case, yes, you would be very much right in thinking that your salary is lower than the expected, unless I've missed something.

The Guide to Implementation, in section 3, reports the contacts in case of problems, where there is also a link to a help desk. I suggest you to read that section and follow the links and contacts there provided. In particular, there is a [National Contact Point for Sweden](https://ec.europa.eu/info/funding-tenders/opportunities/portal/screen/support/ncp;sortQuery=country;countryGroups=MS;countries=20001001;functions=5). However, I suggest you to first formulate your question to the contact point not as an accusation, but as a request of information on the calculation of your salary.

If, instead, as suggested by Pieter Naaijkens in a comment below, you're moving to the US, the coefficient would be 0.991, yielding  €5430. Even in this case, after converting to USD, your salary seems lower than expected.

Comment: The country coefficient for the US applies if the time in the US is the outgoing phase of the fellowship.

Comment: @PieterNaaijkens You're right, but the OP says that they go from the US to Sweden. Anyway, I'll edit my answer to take into account your remark.

Comment: The OP says that are going to the US from Sweden

Comment: I wonder if there is a misunderstand of the term "gross salary costs". We are assuming that this just means pre-tax, but it could in fact include all sort of other on-costs. For example in the UK, the grant chargeable on costs for a postdoc are about 1.5x the pre-tax salary the employee receives. In particular in the US i bet health insurance can be counted against it. When i was in the US, my employer was paying $1200 a month for my health insurance.

Comment: @IanSudbery is correct the gross salary cost for the Marie curie includes all salary costs including all employer contributions to pension schemes and various National insurances.

Comment: As mentioned I was told to receive a flat salary of 4130 EUR before tax and around 3000 after. They also told me that they will pay me with Swedish coefficient all the time. Which makes everything to look even more strange. Thank you for you replies, and I have already tried to contact a person from Nation contact point in Sweden.

Comment: @IanSudbery Excellent point. My suspicion is that "gross salary **costs**" is not the same as "gross salary". This is rather unfortunate and I can't really fault OP for getting confused if that's the case.

Comment: @ElenaSubbotina Please, if possible, let us then know the result of your inquiry: it could be certainly useful to future readers.

Comment: I can clarify once again the numbers, I will take it in SEK. I was told to be paid 31000SEK after taxes, (42300SEK before) for my outgoing stage-US, and incoming stage - Sweden. I was a told I will be paid with Swedish coefficient all the time  and if US coefficient was applied I would have gotten 25000SEK/month after tax during my stay in US, which is lower than the minimum required by my University in US. I find wierd that my department decided to pay me with Swedish coefficient and that with US coefficient I would not be able to go at all due to too low salary. That is why I am suspicious.

Comment: I have perofmed calculations taking into account full cost of my salary for my employer (using https://statsskuld.se/jobb/berakna-bruttolon) If the numbers: 4880 EUR/month +600 EUR/month (mobility) and 1.218 living cost coefficient for Sweden are correct, I still should get more without University topping out anything.

Comment: The website you posted shows the gross salary for a given net salary. It doesn't show the gross cost to the employer, which is higher than the gross salary, particularly in the US. Also, the EU won't pay for the Swedish multiplier to be applied in the US. If that happens, either the Swedish or US host must be paying for it. But it does seem worth asking for details of how it is calculated.

Comment: @Ian sudbery, the website does show the full cost employer pays ("arbetsgivaren betalar" or "the employer pays", for net salary of 35000SEK it is around 67000SEK). I however do not know who should pay this amount the university or the EU. Anyway, I just want to understand, how it works and will post the outcome of my situation.

Comment: As I have promised I write how my situation was finally resolved. The main reason for too low salary turned out to be very high taxes in Sweden, which in my case is 57% plus 30% of the residue. This money turned out to be not enough for the outgoing phase, because US has lower live cost coefficient. And my department topped it up. However even with this topping up my salary was around 3200-3400 depending on the exchange rate. But!!! Importantly, after a long negotiation period I asked to use part of the the money allocated to "institutional cost and training".

Comment: This money are ment to be used for training and conferences, but at the end of the project if there is smth left they should be paid to the postdoc. But, inportnant to know that it is solely decided by university how these money are used. In addition, these money will be paid as a housing compensation and not as a part of salary, which means that they are not taxed. Hope this info will be helpful for people in the same situation.