# Marie-Curie Fellowship PhD salary

Tags: phd, salary, marie-curie, spain

I have received a Marie curie Ph.D. fellowship in Spain. The salary written in my contract is much lower than what I expected. Although the website has some information regarding the salary [(pdf from the website)](https://ec.europa.eu/info/funding-tenders/opportunities/docs/2021-2027/horizon/wp-call/2021-2022/wp-2-msca-actions_horizon-2021-2022_en.pdf), there is still a lot of confusion among students on what they should expect [(see the different answers to this question).](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/140729/how-much-actual-funding-does-a-marie-curie-fellowship-entail?rq=1)

I was offered around 2700 euros **gross** per month. Calculating my salary using the country correction coefficient and tax rates in Spain, I was expecting 2700 euros **net**. I want to know whether the salary I was offered is what I'm supposed to get (in Spain) and if so why is it so low compared to the advertised values? If anyone knows the actual values of salaries recieved by marie curie fellows, kindly let me know.

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/179060/20058 See also the final comment from the OP which says that it turned out that the taxes where much higher than expected.

Comment: I don't know enough about Spanish taxes to answer this specifically, but it's important to remember that for Marie Curie projects employers can also deduct their tax and other employment costs from the living allowance listed in that linked PDF. So employer social security contributions, contributions they make to a pension fund on your behalf, and other similar costs can all be deducted from your pre-tax salary. This can add up to be quite a bit in some countries, and may explain the difference.

Comment: I've never heard of any employer/scholarship provider that sets an amount of money *net of taxes* --- offers of payment from employers, scholarship providers, etc., are always pre-tax in my experience.

Comment: I'm selected for a DC project in Spain, too and I wonder the net amount very much. In MSCA DC calculations, it is written that 3400€ for life expenses and 600€ for mobility. I've read too many post complaining about the same thing. Did you request the detail of calculation? If you don't mind, could you share exact amount?

Comment: I have access to my payroll and it seems that its almost 40 percentage of taxes and other deductions. The salary that I receive in hand is about 2100 euros